# Direct URL Route works fine, but not with domain name

Tags: angular, typescript

Im being asked to do a website in angular and accept direct parameters for a client at the URL level.

For example, a sales agent will have a website like [www.website.com/agent/2021](http://www.website.com/agent/2021) and customize the site based on his ID (2021 in this case). I made this work just fine by setting this at routing.module:

```
{ path: '', component: AgentComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: AgentComponent },
```

Where

```
path: 'agent/:code', component: AgentComponent,
```

It all works perfect, except than when I browse [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) straight, it shows a blank page. This is fine, because the code at app.component.ts runs first. Ive setup an agent ID 1 at the database so when someone browses the URL straight (without a route), I can route to [www.website.com/agent/1](http://www.website.com/agent/1) but at this point, I cannot figure out if the user accessed the direct URL, or a URL containing a route (such as  [www.website.com/agent/2021](http://www.website.com/agent/2021))

Is there a solution to detect if the client went straight to the URL ([www.website.com](http://www.website.com)) and in such case, redirect to [www.website.com/agent/1](http://www.website.com/agent/1), or if the client is coming from a direct route ([www.website.com/agent/2021](http://www.website.com/agent/2021)), keep him on that route?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'agent/1'}`

Comment: Hey Vishnudev. That didnt work, and the direct routes do not work with that path. Thanks.

Comment: 'does not work' is hardly a description of the issue. cna you be more specific? do you see an error in console? any errors at all?

Comment: No errors at all on the console, blurfus. The page is just blank, now for both cases, the root and the agent/:code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it reversed.

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo:'agent/1' }, 
{ path: '', component: AgentComponent },
```